# How to merge all exports from different files into one?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

e.g.

```
./one.const.js ---------> module.exports = {};
./two.const.js ----------> module.exports = {};
./index.js---------------> module.exports = mergedExports; // mergedExports: {one: {}, two: {}};
```

In a folder say `xyz` I have two files with *.const.js filenames and there's one index.js. I want an automated code in index.js which merges all the exports from *.const.js

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  This seems to be counter to the goals of node.js modularity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to do this on startup:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const regex = new RegExp('.const.js$')
const files = fs.readdirSync('.').filter((fileName) => regex.test(fileName))

const mergedExports = {};

for (let i =0; i < files.length; i++) {
    const fileName = files[i].split('.const.js')[0]
    mergedExports[fileName] = require(`./${files[i]}`)
}

module.exports = mergedExports
```

If you want to merge the exports into a single object, update the for  loop to:

```
for (let i =0; i < files.length; i++) {
    mergedExports = {  ...mergedExports,
                       ...require(`./${files[i]}`),
                    }
}
```

Comment: It works like a charm. But one question though, the key name of the final export is the same as the file name i.e. `mergedExports ------> {"one.const.js": {}, "two.const.js" : {}};` can we rename it to only one and two?

Comment: This script already does that, see the line which says `const fileName = files[i].split('.const.js')[0]`

Comment: Oh, I am so sorry! I was trying with a different filename. ;-)

Comment: One more thing, what if I don't want any keys just merge every export into one single object? @ayush-gupta

Answer (score 3):

> In a folder say `xyz` I have two files with *.const.js filenames and there's one index.js

The default behavior of require() is that it will look inside the xyz folder for an index.js if you don't manually specify which file to import.

index.js

```
exports.One = require("./one.const.js");
exports.Two = require("./two.const.js");
```

outside.js

```
const { One, Two } = require("./xyz");
```